# simplify the code for getting a string with unique words, get rid of unnecessary functions

Tags: sql, arrays, string, postgresql, performance

There is such a SQL query

```
SELECT 
    t1.id AS id,
    array_to_string(
        array(
            SELECT DISTINCT unnest(
                string_to_array(
                    STRING_AGG(t2.words, '|')
                , '|')
            )
        )
    , '|') AS words
FROM libraries t1
JOIN library_file_relationships r ON t1.id = r.library_id
JOIN files t2 ON r.file_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

- The `words` fields that contain words are extracted from the `files` table,
  separated by the delimiter '|'
- then the fields are split into individual words separated by the '|' delimiter and
  converted into an array
- only unique values are left from the array
- which are then put back into a string using the '|' delimiter.

I've done head-on that this algorithm is guaranteed to work, but as for me there are a lot of unnecessary functions of working with strings and arrays, as it seems to me

Is it possible to simplify it (and thus speed it up)?

**We need:** in each group of strings containing words with '|' separator, create one string containing only unique words (without repeats) with '|' separator.

Comment: Could you add some simple data and the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

It's debatable whether this is simpler. 3 functions instead of 5, but adding a cte.

What you are doing seems perfectly reasonable.

```
CREATE TABLE libraries (
    id INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE library_file_relationships (
    library_id INTEGER,
    file_id INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE files (
    id INTEGER,
    words TEXT
);

INSERT INTO libraries (id) VALUES
    (1), (2), (3), (4), (5),
    (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);

INSERT INTO library_file_relationships (library_id, file_id) VALUES
    (1, 101), (2, 102), (3, 103), (4, 104), (5, 105),
    (6, 106), (7, 107), (8, 108), (9, 109), (10, 110);

INSERT INTO files (id, words) VALUES
    (101, 'word1|word1|word2'),
    (102, 'word2|word3|word3'),
    (103, 'word4|word4|word5'),
    (104, 'word5|word6|word6'),
    (105, 'word7|word7|word8'),
    (106, 'word8|word9|word9'),
    (107, 'word10|word10|word11'),
    (108, 'word11|word12|word12'),
    (109, 'word13|word13|word14'),
    (110, 'word14|word15|word15');

with cte as (
  select
    distinct 
    t1.id as id,
    unnest(string_to_array(t2.words, '|')) as word_pivot
  from
    libraries t1
    join library_file_relationships r on t1.id = r.library_id
    join files t2 on r.file_id = t2.id
)
select
  id,
  string_agg(word_pivot, '|') as unique_tokens
from
  cte
group by
  id;
```

| id | unique_tokens |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | word1|word2 |
| 2 | word2|word3 |
| 3 | word4|word5 |
| 4 | word5|word6 |
| 5 | word7|word8 |
| 6 | word8|word9 |
| 7 | word10|word11 |
| 8 | word11|word12 |
| 9 | word13|word14 |
| 10 | word14|word15 |

Comment: Well, I need performance first of all so that the query would run as fast as possible, so I thought I could achieve this by reducing the number of functions